# OpenSSL: how to download full certificate chain

Tags: x.509

I have the following X509 certificate in PEM format:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

It contains only the leaf certificate. I'd like to convert it into a PEM file containing the full certificate chain (i.e. in this case a file that starts with this certificate and then has two more BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE brackets containing Regulated CA 02 and Root CA IV). The certificate uses the Authority Information Access extension to list the download url to get the issuer certificate. Can OpenSSL somehow recursively search for and download complete certificate chain, or do I need to do that by hand?

Comment: *"Can OpenSSL somehow recursively search for and download complete certificate chain,"* - No, it can't do this automatically. But you can try to follow the *CA Issuers* URL in the certificate as long there exist one.

Comment: In addition to using AIA in the certs, my favorite transparency log indexer https://crt.sh has [one known cert for that intermediate](https://crt.sh/?id=2060705007) and by clicking on Issuer you can find the [one known cert for that root](https://crt.sh/?id=2060705008) -- even though it doesn't show them as logged!